# Getting PID of dependency in systemd?

Tags: systemd

I would like to write a systemd unit file that needs to pass to the exec command the PID of one of its dependencies. In the unit file I would like to have:

```
ExecStart=bar -p <PID of foo.service>
Requires=foo.service
After=foo.service
```

Is there a way to get the PID of a required dependency in some easy way? Couldn't locate anything in the manual nor an example in any of the unit files on an Ubuntu desktop.

The use case is to create a simple unit file that can be used to attach the JProfiler daemon to a Java based service in order to do remote performance debugging. The command to attach the profiler needs the PID of the JVM.

Answer (score 1):

From [`man systemctl`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemctl.html#-p):

> `-p`, `--property=`
>
> When showing unit/job/manager properties with the **show** command, limit
> display to properties specified in the argument. The argument should
> be a comma-separated list of property names, **such as "`MainPID`"**. [...]

So `systemctl show -p MainPID foo` will display `MainPID=<pid>` (rather than just the pid). Using an additional `--value` (or the combination parameter `-P` (uppercase) for recent enough *systemd*) will provide just the value:

> `--value`
>
> When printing properties with show, only print the value, and skip the
> property name and "=". Also see option -P above.
>
> Added in version 230.

So if service *foo* can be identified by its Main PID (ie: the target process isn't actually a sub-process of the main pid), this could be used:

```
/bin/sh -c 'pid=$(systemctl show --value -p MainPID foo); [ "$pid" -ne 0 ] && exec bar -p $pid || exit 1'
```

If not in its own script, one can [use the prefix `:` before the executable line to avoid any parsing from *systemd*](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/latest/systemd.service.html#id-1.9.8):

> | Prefix | Effect |
> | --- | --- |
> | ... | ... |
> | ":" | If the executable path is prefixed with ":", environment variable substitution (as described by the "Command Lines" section below) is not applied. |
> | ... | ... |

thus keeping it the same in the service file:

```
ExecStart=:/bin/sh -c 'pid=$(systemctl show --value -p MainPID foo); [ "$pid" -ne 0 ] && exec bar -p $pid || exit 1'
```

Comment: adding the `--value` flag (e.g. `systemctl show foo.service --property=MainPID --value
`) .... or by using `-P` (uppercase P) (e.g. `systemctl show foo.service -P MainPID`) ... allows to just get the value (without the key). See https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemctl.html#--value ... and https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemctl.html#-P

Comment: Using [`:` as the prefix for the command](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/latest/systemd.service.html#id-1.9.8) seems to make systemd basically ignore `$`s in the command line, so it could eliminate the mangling